# How to secure remote console LUKS passphrase entry?

Tags: luks

Say I have a Linux server running on my own metal and wish to encrypt the hard drive using LUKS.

After a power failure, how can I enter my passphrase remotely without compromising it?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/220803/56961